# How can I detect when the user has swiped an editable UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have an editable UITableView. By default the user can swipe and the Delete button will show up. I would like to hide some elements on my UITableView cell when this occurs. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try overriding the willTransitionToState method in your custom UITableViewCell. In particular you would be interested in the UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask state.

Comment: Good one. I hide it in `UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask` and it did the trick

Answer (score 9):

Oh c'mon:

> ### tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:
>
> ...
>
> **Discussion**
>
> **This method is called when the user swipes horizontally across a row**;
>   as a consequence, the table view sets its editing property to YES
>   (thereby entering editing mode) and displays a Delete button in the
>   row identified by `indexPath`. In this "swipe to delete" mode the
>   table view does not display any insertion, deletion, and reordering
>   controls. This method gives the delegate an opportunity to adjust the
>   application's user interface to editing mode. When the table exits
>   editing mode (for example, the user taps the Delete button), the table
>   view calls `tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:`.

[Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate)

And then throw some `[[cell viewWithTag:<#View's tag number#>] setHidden:YES]` for your own views.

Comment: This will certainly work, but I would think that the display and layout of the cell would be the responsibility of the cell, not the view controller that contains the table. Just an OO-purist perspective.

Comment: I'm also an OO-purist, but it all depends on how OP is adding its custom views to the cell, and I assumed it was the typical `addSubview`. I usually use another custom UITableViewCell subclass and add a `[(CustomCell*)cell hideYerThingies]`.

Comment: +1 for hideYerThingies (gotta use that someday), but I'd still handle it in the cell willTransitionToState in cases where the currently-being-deleted cell scrolls off screen and get reused.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you modify the pertinent elements of the `– tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:` is called?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the user wants to editing something in his `tableView`, this method gets called

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

if(editing){
     // Entered Edit mode

     // Show the new tableView and reload it.
} 

else {
    // End of edit mode

    // Bring back the tableview and again reload it. 
}


[super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your UI in `tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:` and Restore in `tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:`.